# Back up server in separate domain

Tags: networking, backup, domain, backupexec, symantec

I currently have a backup server on one domain, say domain A. This backup server has Backup exec 11d installed on it, and is responsible for backing up numerous other servers in the same domain.

I now have a server on another domain which requires backing up. It would make sense to utilise the existing back up server for this task. Would I need to create a trust between the two domains in order to achieve what I require? Has anyone done anything similar and have any useful information on the subject?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BackupExec agent (once it's installed) will run under the Local System account. You'll need to create a new BackupExec Logon Account that's valid in the other domain and those are the credentials that BackupExec will use to connect to and backup the remote system once you've selected the remote system and told BackupExec which Logon Account to use in your selection list(s).

Answer (score 1):

We do this all the time. Different subnets, different domains and a single backup machine that's on neither of the subnets or domains.

Just as long as the backup server can talk to the machine on the other domain, you shouldn't have a problem. The setup might be a bit different (because backupexec uses AD credentials to install the backup agents, but you can manually specify them), but it can be done.